# Ratio symbol in multiple regression

Tags: regression, notation, ratio

I am running a multiple regression of the following form: 
Ratio Y = X0 + Ratio X1 + Ratio X2
I was wondering if there would be a symbol I could use for the 'Ratio'?

I found a [similar type of question in the maths stack exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44771/is-there-an-analogue-to-the-delta-symbol-for-ratios) but this did not seem applicable to my model.

Comment: Welcome to our site! I don't think this is a silly question at all - I have edited it to make it a little more "to the point".

Comment: Don't know of a symbol for "Ratio" but your question also raises the issue of what these "Ratios" represent. In some cases you would not want to do standard multiple regression with ratio variables.

Comment: Can you explain what "Ratio Y" means? Do you mean that "Y is calculated as a ratio of two quantities"? If so you'll have to explain what these ratios consist of; there are a host of potential issues to consider, from the possibility in some situations of spurious correlation to the problem that linear functions of ratios aren't always $\geq$0 even though the ratios might always be $\geq$0 to problems with the variance specification, ...

Comment: Yes, I am aware that there could be fallacies using this type of regression model. Basically, I have two groups and the ratios represent the performance of members of one group divided by the average performance of those from the other group, for a given variable. I could as well have taken the difference (delta) in performance, but the ratio would make more logical sense for the research that I am doing and also allows for direct comparison between the different variables. I was hoping that, like delta, there would be a symbol that I could use for the ratio notation.